# Is it possible to run a node.js CL app without using the global folder?

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to know whether it is possible somehow to run a node.js command line app without using the global folder, i.e. no `npm install -g` or `npm link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a cli that is npm installed locally without using anything else, you can do (assuming webpack):

```
node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Just check that directory `./node_modules/.bin`

Comment: This answer is so obvious that I could not see it in the first place. I prefer it because of its simplicity and because it doesn't require installing any third party module.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `npx`  would work for you.

```
$ npm i -D webpack
$ npx webpack ...
```